# Derivation of acceptance probability from Linero, Yang (2018)

Tags: bayesian, conditional-probability, prior, metropolis-hastings, mcmc-acceptance-rate

I am wondering how this paper *[Bayesian Regression Tree Ensembles that Adapt to
Smoothness and Sparsity](https://academic.oup.com/jrsssb/article/80/5/1087/7048381)* by Linero & Yang (2018) derived the acceptance probability for $\sigma$.

The authors give $\sigma$ a half Cauchy prior, $\sigma \sim \operatorname{Cauchy}_{+}(0, \widehat{\sigma}_{\text {lasso }})$. To update $\sigma$ they say the following:

> Let $R=\left(R_1, \ldots, R_n\right)$ be the residuals, $R_i=Y_i-f\left(X_i\right)$. Note that, under a flat prior for $\sigma^{-2}$, the full-conditional of $\sigma^{-2}$ is $\mathrm{Ga}(N / 2+$ $1,\|R\|^2 / 2$ ). We use this full-conditional under the flat prior as a proposal distribution for $\sigma^{-2}$; after adjusting for the Jacobian of the transformation, the acceptance probability becomes
> $$
> A\left(\sigma \rightarrow \sigma^{\prime}\right)=\frac{\operatorname{Cauchy}_{+}\left(\sigma^{\prime} \mid 0, \widehat{\sigma}_{\text {lasso }}\right) \sigma^{\prime 3}}{\text { Cauchy }_{+}\left(\sigma \mid 0, \widehat{\sigma}_{\text {lasso }}\right) \sigma^3} \wedge 1.
> $$

I get the Jacobian bit of it, but I'm wondering how they managed to get from the Gamma distribution of $\sigma^{-2}$ to the half-Cauchy distribution of $\sigma$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Metropolis-Rosenbluth-Hastings acceptance ratio is the traditional
$$\frac{\text{target new}}{\text{target old}}\times\frac{\text{proposal old}}{\text{proposal new}}$$
where, most conveniently, the proposal here is equal to the likelihood, up to the power transform, hence a ratio
$$\frac{\text{prior new}\times\text{likelihood new}}{\text{prior old}\times\text{likelihood old}}\times\frac{\text{likelihood old}\times\text{Jacobian old}}{\text{likelihood new}\times\text{Jacobian new}}$$
simplifying into
$$\frac{\text{prior new}}{\text{prior old}}\times\frac{\text{Jacobian old}}{\text{Jacobian new}}$$
which is the expression given in the [paper](https://academic.oup.com/jrsssb/article/80/5/1087/7048381).